# Graph theory problem 4 colourable graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The following is a question from MIT 6.042 course. Can someone please help me in understanding this question?

Let (s1, s2, ..., sn) be an arbitrarily distributed sequence of the number 1, 2, ..., n − 1, n. For instance, for n = 5, one arbitrary sequence could be (5, 3, 4, 2, 1).
Define the graph G=(V,E) as follows:

1. V ={v1,v2,...,vn}
2. e = (vi,vj) ∈ E if either:

(a) j=i+1,for1≤i≤n−1

(b) i=sk,andj=sk+1 for1<=k<=n−1

Prove that this graph is 4-colorable for any (s1, s2, ..., sn).

Comment: Which part of this question do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't understand what kind of graph are we talking about here? I can't connect the two points a and b with graph G

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example. Suppose we have the sequence $(s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5, s_6, s_7) = (3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5)$.

Our graph will have vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6, v_7$. Its edges will be defined in two steps.

From part (a), we just get the edges $v_1 v_2, v_2 v_3, v_3 v_4, v_4 v_5, v_5v_6, v_6 v_7$:

[image]

From part (b), we go through the sequence $(3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5)$ in order, and get the edges $v_3 v_1, v_1 v_7, v_7 v_2, v_2 v_6, v_6 v_4, v_4 v_6)$:

[image]

The final graph combines both sources of edges:

[image]

You must prove that this result will always be $4$-colorable.

Comment: Bro I understood the question now, finally!!

Comment: The proof would be something like this: We can colour the first graph with just two colours by colouring all the even vertices with colour 'a' and the odd vertices with color 'b'. Now in the second graph every vertex have degree 2 at max. Combining both together we have a graph whereby every vertex is adjacent to at max 4 vertices. The two nodes connected to any vi is already coloured with different colour than vi. So we have already used two colours. what remains is the 2 vertices it is adjacent to from graph 2 those can be coloured with 2 different colours. so in total we used 4 colours.

Comment: is my Proof correct?

Comment: You are right that you can color each of the two graphs from part (a) and part (b) with two colors. But you should think more carefully about how to combine them.

Comment: I didn't understood. what I'm saying is that in the final graph we have vi which is at max connected to 4 vertices. The first two vertices are from graph 1 so I can use two colours 'a' and 'b' to colour these adjacent vertices of vi. Then we have the other vertices its adjacent to from graph 2. They can be given two new colours, 'c' and 'd'. So in total I used 4 colours.

Comment: In the first step, you already colored all $n$ vertices with colors 'a' and 'b' from the first graph. Then, in the second step, you recolored $v_i$'s neighbors from the second graph with colors 'c' and 'd'. How many $v_i$'s are you going to do this for - and when you're done, won't you have a coloring using only colors 'c' and 'd', which may cause problems from edges with the first graph? (If you do this with the graph from my example, what will the final color of each vertex be?)

Comment: in the first step the colours are temporary colours. So for e.g the graph in your example would be coloured like so: a-b-a-b-a-b-a. now I add edges from the second graph. So I see that v1 is adjacent to v3 so I color v3 with 'c'(so I used 3 colours so far 'a','b',and 'c') then I see v2 is adjacent  to v6 and v7 so I color v6 and v7 with 'c' and 'd'. So I used four colours already. Then I go to v4 and see its matched with v6 but v6 is already coloured with 'c' so I move on.. and so like this I colour the graph. But lets say v4 was adjacent to v8 and v9 then they will be coloured c-d,still valid

Comment: In larger examples, this can go wrong. After a while, you might get to a vertex $v_i$ which is adjacent to $v_j$ in the second graph, but you've already recolored $v_{j-1}$ and $v_{j+1}$ by 'c' and 'd'. Then there's nothing you can do to fix $v_j$.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll think about it. I do see the problem

Comment: Plus I really appreciate you explaining this to me. you are amazing.!! I finally understood the question. I'm a self learner so I really appreciate this a lot. Also it would mean a lot to me if by any chance you would like to share some other platform that we can connect over like Skype or telegram or some other messaging platform.

Comment: I would prefer not to do that, but you're likely to get more answers even on Math StackExchange once you can say how you've begun to engage with a problem and gotten stuck.

Comment: So I came up with this Proof; When we combine the two graphs, we get a graph where a vertex Vi is adjacent to at max 4 vertices. The vertices Vi, Vi-1 and Vi+1 can be coloured with at max 3 colours because we can have at max something like a triangle and triangle can only be coloured with three colours say 'a','b' and 'c' as in the case of v1,v2, and v3. Now suppose Vi is adjacent to vertices from outside the triangle which can be at max two vertices. Those two vertices can be coloured with either colours of Vi-1 and Vi+1 and some new color 'd'. So we use four colours at max in worst case....

Comment: Hence the graph is four colourable

Comment: I would rather not keep looking for holes in the arguments in comments. I will say that there's a much easier approach to combine the two colorings that you're not seeing yet.

Comment: Another Proof try; The first graph can be coloured with two colours by colouring even vertices with 'a' and odd vertices with 'b'. These will be temporary colours. Then we add edges from second graph. Suppose Vi is even then if the two vertices that vi is adjacent to from graph 2 is even then Vi has to be coloured with 'c' as it's adjacent to an even vertex. We can go along like this and say another vertex Vj is odd and its adjacent to an odd vertex from graph 2 then we colour it with 'd' if the color of one of them is already not different. Hence the graph is four colourable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139205/discussion-between-azhar-and-misha-lavrov).

Comment: is the above proof correct? You may not identify the flaw but just mention if it's correct or not.

Comment: It's not. It's not enough to just use the fact that every vertex in the second graph has at most two edges; it is important that the second graph is also 2-colorable.

Comment: Can you give me the solution?

Comment: just a reminder:) I would be really grateful if you can give me the solution:)